# how to increase the size of input values or post values in php?

Tags: php, size

I have tried to increase the values which are memory limit and max_post_size even upload_size like that:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','50M');
ini_set('post_max_size','50M');
ini_set('memory_limit', '51M')
```

but when i enter the long text to text area , it does not post or exceed input size extc? why?
Note: I can enter this value to database it is not related with it.

my code below:

```
<div id="duzenle" style="<?=$duzenleme?>">
<form method="post" action="../../phps/icerikKayit.php">
<div style="width:770px;">
    <div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <input value="<?= $gelen_id ?>" name="gelen_id" type="text" id="gelen_id" size="60" style="display: none;" />
        <input value="<?= $button ?>" name="button" type="text" id="gelen_id" size="60" style="display: none;" />
        <input value="<?= $kategori_id ?>" name="kategori_id" type="text" id="kategori_id" size="60" style="display: none;" />
        <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size:12px;">Başlık</td><td width="10"> : </td><td><input value="<?= $baslik ?>" name="baslik" type="text" id="baslik" size="60" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size:12px;">Açıklama</td><td> : </td><td><input value="<?= $aciklama ?>" name="aciklama" type="text" id="aciklama" size="60" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size:12px;">Meta Tag</td><td> : </td><td><input value="<?= $meta_verisi ?>" name="meta_verisi" type="text" id="meta_verisi" size="60" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size:12px;">Ek Bilgiler</td><td> : </td><td><input value="<?= $ek_bilgiler ?>" name="ek_bilgiler" type="text" id="ek_bilgiler" size="60" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight: bold; font-size:12px; vertical-align:top;">İçerik</td><td style="vertical-align: top;"> : </td>
        <td>
            <textarea id="icerik" name="icerik" rows="40" cols="40" style="width: 100%">
            <?= $icerik ?>
            </textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><br />
            <input type="submit" name="save" value="Kaydet" />
            <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Temizle" /> 
            <input type="button" value="Close" onClick="hideWindow();"/>

        </td>
    </tr>



    </table>    
    </div>
```

Comment: The upload and POST limits are processed *before* the script is executed.  They need to be altered in php.ini or in .htaccess.

Comment: I tried them and I restarted it but it does not still work

Comment: Check `phpinfo`, make sure you modified the correct ini file.

Answer (score 1):

**textarea** is an html element and it works independent of what PHP settings are. It will still limit itself to html max limit nomatter what php value you set

Comment: How can increase the textarea limit?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't quiet got your question but if you are using `maxlength` attribute than you wont be able to exceed more than the characters defined, nothing to do with PHP and if you are posting and it's not getting posted in your database than probably you need to check the database filed type, whether you are using `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`

Comment: it is a textarea that's why I cannot define maxlenght in textarea tags my main problem is related to the post or char input size limit

Comment: Also, I tried to enter the value to db in manually it works correctly

Comment: @user1702486 I doubt you css or the `maxlength` attribute is disturbing here, also be sure you are not using any `strlen()`

Comment: My form does not post specific content. Can post all the form content but not just one of them, which includes lots lots of text, this is my main problem in fact.

Comment: @user1702486 are you sure your variable is actually holding so much of text?

Comment: No, I am not sure, I am asking it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are handling string with "addslashes" or something like, so you can create a array of your larger text with help of JS and try to use that.

Comment: no it is not related with character style. I tried to all text includes 'a' such as aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Comment: my point is, onSubmit split your larger text by 200 chars in one go and create chunks of larger text than post your form with array data, else if you can post your code will  be great for clear understanding.

Comment: I used same code you have pasted above with more then 1000 Lines where each line contains 200 chars but didn;t get any error. Form was successfully get post to my server and i was able to retrieve the values.

Comment: how can do it? what is the problem you think

Answer (score 0):

Setting the php values have nothing to do with input string.To increase the size of the text area , you should do it in html by using the attributes **cols and rows**.Increasing the *cols* and *rows* attribute increases the size of the text area.

Example:

```
<textarea cols=40 rows=80 ></textarea>
```

and ***`to exceed 50mb limit you will need atleast 50mb of text, that's around 500K lines of text`***.

If you need to limit the size of the text that reaches your database then you should truncate it out in php.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913342/php-truncate-string-if-longer-than-limit-and-put-some-omission-at-the-end-simil) solution here shows you how to truncate or limit the string

[php truncate string if longer than limit and put some omission at the end..similar to ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913342/php-truncate-string-if-longer-than-limit-and-put-some-omission-at-the-end-simil)