# How do I show '...' when the WordPress title exceeds length

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function which trims the title to a certain length. It does trim the title properly, but always shows '...' even if the title doesn't exceed the length.

Does anyone know how to make it so the '...' will only show if the title is too long?

```
// Title Excerpt//
function the_titlesmall($before = '', $after = '', $echo = true, $length = false) { $title = get_the_title();

    if ( $length && is_numeric($length) ) {
        $title = substr( $title, 0, $length );
    }

    if ( strlen($title)> 0 ) {
        $title = apply_filters('the_titlesmall', $before . $title . $after, $before, $after);
        if ( $echo )
            echo $title;
        else
            return $title;
    }
}
//End Title Excerpt
```

PHP in loop

```
<?php the_titlesmall('', '', true, '15') ?>
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913342/php-truncate-string-if-longer-than-limit-and-put-some-omission-at-the-end-simil

Comment: Could your problem be solved using CSS's `text-overflow: ellipsis` at display time, rather than fiddling with the actual data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Focusing on trimming the title.

Try adding this function to your `functions.php`.

```
function short_title($after = '', $length) {
    $mytitle = get_the_title();
    if ( strlen($mytitle) > $length ) {
    $mytitle = substr($mytitle,0,$length);
    echo $mytitle . $after;
    } else {
    echo $mytitle;
    }
}
```

Then, wherever you want the title to appear put the following: `<?php short_title('...', 40); ?>` That would limit it to 40 characters, and add an ... if it exceeds it.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? You're putting `<?php wp_trim_excerpt( $text ) ?>` where you want the excerpt to appear, right?

Comment: @user3648353 check out my latest edit. It should help you more. I misunderstood that you were asking for the title to be shortened, not the excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't trim it at display time using CSS's `text-overflow: ellipsis`, I'd probably just use [mb_strimwidth](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php). It's what it's designed for. For basic use, something like this, perhaps:

```
<?php echo mb_strimwidth(get_the_title(), 0, 20, '...'); ?>
```

...and roll it into your own function as necessary.